# given a random set of boxes and a set of spaces, how can you find the optimal combination?

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation, bin-packing

I have kind of an interesting assignment and I'm not sure where to begin.

Imagine you have a set of spaces (all same size) and a set of boxes (variable integer size, 1 or 2 or 3 units of volume). Each space can hold 4 units of volume.  Given a random set of boxes, what would be the optimal combination(s) that would leave the most open space (i.e. pack in the densest).

I don't expect anyone to write my code for me, but i could really use some advice on where to start for such a problem. Can anyone help?

I tried listing all the permutations and then choosing the ones with the most "open space" but it was computationally very expensive. I'm using C# if that makes a difference.

the code is kind of longwinded so here is the pseudo code

```
int [] boxes = new int[20] // I will be given an array of length 20 representing 20 boxes.
// the values of the boxes[] array will be random integers of either 1, 2 or 3
foreach (var v in boxes[]){boxes[v] = random(1 or 2 or 3)

//now i take the set of boxes and come up with all the permutations with a permutation function
int [,] permutearray = new int[20!,20] // each row is the index of a permutation, with the y value as the size.

//permutearray will be a set of numbers representing a possible combination of boxes like
{{1,3,2,2,1,2,3,4 ...},{3,1,2,3,2,1,1, ...}...}

//now check each row to see how many spaces it would take to contain the boxes in that order 
// do this using another function i call "fitcheck" on each row/column of permutearray
//fitcheck reports an array of numbers which represent the permutation index

int [] solutions = new [max_solutions]
solutions = fitcheck(permutearray)
```

Comment: Please show the code you've got so far.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem and related problems

Comment: @TimS. That was super helpful I cant believe i never found that in my internet trawling before.